# How do I capture output from rasa chatbot?

Tags: python, nltk, chatbot, sentiment-analysis, rasa

I have a working Rasa chatbot that does some simple sentiment analysis using NLTK (vader_lexicon) on the user input. This is done similar to this tutorial: https://rasa.com/blog/enhancing-rasa-nlu-with-custom-components/

So, what I am trying to do is to access the bot's response so that I can put this through my sentiment analyser. After this, I would like to access the last 5 responses and do some sentiment analysis based on all 5 responses given by the chatbot.

I would gladly share some code, but I am not sure what to share at the moment.

Comment: Yes this should be possible.  Can you share a small reproducible example, with a minimal viable chatbot that generates a response from a small set of user input.  It is very hard for people to help you without this.

Comment: I am not sure what I should share. I added a link to the tutorial followed to get the sentiment through NLTK for the user input. But I am not so sure where I should alter the bot in order to get the sentiment of the bot's response.

Comment: I get an error trying to access that link.  Try to delete as many lines as you can from your existing code to create a simple chatbot that does some simple sentiment analysis.  It sounds like you just need to take the output from the chatbot and run it through a new sentiment classifier / scorer

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do :) But I am not so sure how to access that output from the chatbot.

Comment: In which case your code just needs to create a chatbot.  It doesn't need the sentiment classifier part.  Your question can be "how do I capture output from this chatbot"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I changed the post accordingly :)

Comment: in code I see `message.set(..., [entity],...)` and maybe you should use `print()` to check what you have in `entity`

Comment: Once you run the response thru the sentiment analysis, what do you want to do with the results? Is the response a static utterance in your `domain.yml` or does it come from a separate NLG server or custom action? Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you can monitor the conversation using an Event Broker as discussed [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/next/event-brokers/) but it depends on what you are trying to do.